# Tomcat - Is there any way to filter _ from domain name coming from /etc/hosts

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have mapped  XXX.XX.XX.XX IP  to anu_test in my /etc/hosts file.

NOTE : (XXX.XX.XX.XX is my machine where my tomcat is hosted)

And when I try to download the file stored in XXX.XX.XX.XX IP via hostname from my client(Terminal).

```
curl anu_test:4711/files/action.txt -v -o myoutput.txt
```

I see that I get below error from tomcat

```
May 13, 2020 1:40:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor parseHost
INFO: The host [anu_test:4711] is not valid
 Note: further occurrences of request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The character [_] is never valid in a domain name.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser$DomainParseState.next(HttpParser.java:1132)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.readHostDomainName(HttpParser.java:1028)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:66)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:40)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:226)
        at
```

AFAIK tomcat doesn't allow _ in domain names .

Below are my questions.

1.is there any way where we can block this request from tomcat by adding a filter?

2. Is there any advantage of adding some filters (Remote Host Filter) when compared to Tomcat by-default rejecting these requests with 400 Bad Request? Basically, can someone explain why should someone add some filters to handle these _ and what are the advantages?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this URL `http://anu_test:8080` rather than `anu_test`

, If not working try to create Alias to your site, I assume that the application war name is `webapps`

```
</Host>
      <Host name="anu_test.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      <Alias>www.anu_test.com</Alias>
      <Context path="" docBase="webapps" debug="0" privileged="true" />
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
             pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false" />
</Host>
```

[Resource](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-access-a-java-web-application-by-a-domain-name-using-tomcat-8)